# Disable .node_repl_history file

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, history, read-eval-print-loop

Is it possible to disable the node-history of read-eval-print-loop (REPL) stored in the .node_repl_history file in the home directory(~)?

Im using macOS High Sierra, and node is installed through home-brew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable it by setting the `NODE_REPL_HISTORY` environment variable to `""`.

You can read more about the environment variables and REPL in the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_environment_variable_options).

Comment: Thanks! But where/how is this done? How do you set the NODE_REPL_HISTORY to "" ? In the bash shell or in the node shell, or must I edit a file somewhere?

Comment: There are a couple ways to do it on a mac: http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/28/set-enviornment-variables-mac-os-x/